# Split Single Row into Multiple Rows Based on Two Timestamp Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to split the following records:

```
DeviceId    StartTime                  EndTime
------------------------------------------------------------
1001        2022-02-12 07:27:00.000    2022-02-12 16:23:00.000
1002        2022-02-14 03:36:00.000    2022-02-14 04:36:00.000
```

Into:

```
DeviceId    Timestamp                   State
-------------------------------------------------
1001        2022-02-12 07:27:00.000     1    
1001        2022-02-12 16:23:00.000     2
1002        2022-02-14 03:36:00.000     1
1002        2022-02-14 04:36:00.000     2
```

The new `State` column should be based on whether the `Timestamp` is a `StartTime` ( = 1), or an `EndTime` ( = 2).

What would be the `t-sql` query to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may unpivot the table using `VALUES` table value constructor:

```
SELECT t.DeviceId, v.[Timestamp], v.[State]
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   (t.StartTime, 1),
   (t.EndTime, 2)
) v ([Timestamp], [State])
```

If you want to add a condition while generating the values, a different statement is needed:

```
SELECT t.DeviceId, v.[Timestamp], v.[State]
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   (CASE WHEN t.Status IN (0, 1) THEN t.StartTime END, 1),
   (t.EndTime, 2)
) v ([Timestamp], [State])
```

Comment: perfect :) one more question, is it possible to add a condition to one tuple, e.g. (t.StartTime and t.status = 0 , 1) assuming status is another column in the table ?

Comment: @khidirsanosi, maybe a `WHERE` clause is more appropriate `... WHERE (v.State = 2) OR (v.State = 1 AND t.Status IN (0, 1))`

Comment: @khidirsanosi, but if you always need two rows for each `DeviceId`: `... (CASE WHEN t.Status IN (0, 1) THEN t.StartTime END, 1)`.